# Does Chrome on iOS support the filessytem API

Tags: ios, api, google-chrome, filesystems

I know chrome now supports the HTML5 filesystem api on desktop and I believe on Android but I have not seen any reference to chrome on ios supporting it. Does anyone know if it does?

Comment: iOS doesn't have a visible filesystem, so how would Chrome on iOS have one?

Answer (score 0):

No. Since iOS doesn't have an open/public filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome on iOS uses Mobile WebKit, which does not support FileSystem or FileWriter APIs.  You can test it out by pointing a device or simulator to [this test page](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/filesystem/filer.js/demos/index.html).

You can learn about the client-side storage and caching options that are available on [this section of the Apple Developer website](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).